# Give an example of continuously differentiable function that satisfy some properties

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Can you give an example of continuously differentiable function that satisfy this properties:

Let $\{(a_i, b_i)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be the family of open subintervals of $[0,1]$ with rationals endpoints. For each $i\geq 1$, let

$$g_i:[a_i,b_i]\to [0,1]$$

be a continuously differentiable function such that

1. $g_i(a_i)=1$, $g_i(b_i)=0$,
2. $\lim_{x\to a_i^+} g_i^{\prime}(x)=0$,
3. $\lim_{x\to b_i^-} g_i^{\prime}(x)=0$.

I have tried to make some examples, this is my attempt:

1. $g_i(x)=\frac{b_i-x}{b_i-a_i}, a_i\leq x \leq b_i$. But, this function not satisfy properties poin (3) and (4).
2. \begin{align*}
   g_i(x)=\begin{cases}
   1,& a_i\leq x < \frac{a_i+b_i}{2}\\
   \frac{16x-4a_i-12b_i}{a_i-b_i},& \frac{a_i+b_i}{2}\leq x < \frac{a_i+3b_i}{4}\\
   0, & \frac{a_i+3b_i}{4}\leq x \leq b_i
   \end{cases}
   \end{align*}
   This function satisfies properties poin (1)-(4), but this is not continuously differentiable.

Finally, I got stuck on finding an example of that function.
Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Are your intervals disjoint?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I think yes, my intervals are disjoint..

Comment: The functions
$$g_i(x):=\cos^2{\pi(x-a_i)\over2(b_i-a_i)}\qquad(i\geq1)$$
would do. –  I think you have not properly described your problem, since you also talk about *one* function that should be constructed. Are you planning to concatenate the $g_i$ somehow?

Comment: @Christian Blatter Yes, I will concatenate the $g_i$ with $f_i$, where $f_i$ is defined by $$f_i(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x<a_i\\ g_i(x), a_i≤x≤b_i\\ 0, x>b_i \end{cases}$$, then I will show that $f_i$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$. Okay, I'll try the function that you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. There are 4 conditions so try a polynomial with 4 c0-efficients, i.e. a cubic $$g(x)=\frac {x-b}{a-b}\cdot (\,A(x-a)^2+B(x-a)+1\,).$$

Comment: Are A and B arbitrary constant? Or can I take for example : A=1, B=2?

Comment: @MathLearner. Compute what g(x) and g'(x) are when x=a  and when x=b, and compare those to Conditions  1.,2.,3. to find what A  and B must be.

Comment: oh I see.. thank you! I will try.